# Build a dashboard from a metric with Datadog

Tags: datadog

Is there any way with Datadog to build an automatic dashboard if a metric is sent for the first time?
Let's say I send a metric with a value and a "path" like `dashboard_name.some_group.metric_value` for the first time. Datadog "checks" if there is already an existent `dashboard_name`. If not builds it. Then it checks if inside the dashboard there is a widget called `some_group`. If not builds it. Then check if there is a metric widget (for example using Timeseries widget). If not builds it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Datadog has this capability built-in.

I've seen people create service-level automations that create a dashboard for their service, and then build that into their Continuous Delivery lifecycle, using the [Dashboards API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/dashboards/) either directly or via a client SDK like [this Python one](https://datadogpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#datadog.api.Dashboard)

There's also providers for [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard) or [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/datadog/dashboard/) that could help here.